# Summing items in listbox

Tags: vb.net, linq, string.format

I am having trouble with this math problem:

```
lsamount.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:n}", Val(exp_amount.Text)))
```

In my Timer code:

```
For i = 0 To lsamount.Items.Count - 1
   TOT = TOT + Val(lsamount.Items(i))
Next i
totalamount.Text = TOT.ToString
```

Is there any simplest way to add this 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another suggestion and only one line of code and no looping... This uses `Linq` to accomplish this.

```
 totalamount.Text = lsamount.Items.Cast(Of String)().Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(x.Replace(",", ""))).ToString
```

Comment: this will add all the items in the listbox?

Comment: I added the `ToString` to the end of it since your setting it to a textbox. When I did it I set this to a double and did a `ToString` on the double for a messagebox so I could see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
totalamount.Text = string.Join("", lsamount.Items)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i think i just solve my problem i used ToString.Replace(",", "")

Answer (score 0):

i think i nailed it
here is my new timer code

```
        Dim TOT As Double
        Dim tmpstr As String
        For i = 0 To lsamount.Items.Count - 1
            tmpstr = lsamount.Items(i).ToString.Replace(",", "")

            TOT = TOT + Val(tmpstr)
        Next i
        totalamount.Text = (String.Format("{0:n}", Val(TOT)))
```

its working fine.